# ssh-copy-id installed through Homebrew errors when trying to copy an SSH key

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I installed `ssh-copy-id` through Homebrew.

When I type `ssh-copy-id -i mykey.pub [path to remote]` I get the following error:

> /usr/local/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: failed to open ID file './mykey': No such file or directory

It appears that it's not finding the key because the regex is cutting off the `.pub`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I am right, Fedora and CentOS systems have some switch for `ssh-copy-id`, that will turn the behaviour to "LEGACY" mode and it will skip all these checks and just do the copy.

Comment: @Jakuje thanks - looks like it isn't available on OSX but would be a useful feature...I'd love to find a way to either contribute it via Gitub or fork it myself and install into my personal homebrew, but not sure about how that process works, or if https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable is where I would start.

Comment: Yes. This is the one. You can find the code here and see that it is just a bash script. Basically if you want to use it, you can just copy the part you want and use it:
https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/contrib/ssh-copy-id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `ssh-copy-id` checks whether there is a valid private key in the same directory as the public key it's uploading.

I was uploading someone else's SSH key so they could access a server. I don't have their private key on my machine, which is why the error occurred.

One option is to just manually remove that check from the script, but it's hacking the Homebrew code.

My solution was to run `touch mykey` to create a blank file using the filename syntax of the corresponding private key to the public key I was uploading (`mykey.pub`).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your explanation. I have resolved the issue by following these simple steps

```
[ceph@monitor ~]$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
[ceph@monitor ~]$ ssh-copy-id ceph@osd-0
```